Understanding inner join in recursive CTE (MySQL)
The code below is from: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/mysql-common-table-expressions/
Data:
CREATE TABLE
categories (
    id int,
    cat_name varchar(100),
    parent_category_id int DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO
    categories
VALUES
    (1, 'Mens', NULL),
    (2, 'Tops', 1),
    (3, 'Jerseys', 2),
    (4, 'England', 3);

Code:
WITH RECURSIVE
category_tree AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        cat_name,
        parent_category_id,
        cat_name AS full_name
    FROM categories
    WHERE parent_category_id IS NULL                
    UNION ALL                                       
    SELECT
        c.id,                                       
        c.cat_name,                                 
        c.parent_category_id,
        CONCAT (ct.full_name, ' > ', c.cat_name)
    FROM categories c
        JOIN category_tree ct 
        ON c.parent_category_id = ct.id             
)
SELECT
    id, full_name
FROM
    category_tree;

categories:
| id | cat_name | parent_category_id |
| ---| ---------| -------------------|
| 1  | Mens     | NULL               |
| 2  | Tops     | 1                  |
| 3  | Jerseys  | 2                  | 
| 4  | England  | 3                  |

category_tree: 
| id | full_name                       |
| ---| ------------------------------- |
| 1  | Mens                            |
| 2  | Mens > Tops                     |
| 3  | Mens > Tops > Jerseys           |
| 4  | Mens > Tops > Jerseys > England |


I have trouble understanding this line: ON c.parent_category_id = ct.id
From my understanding, ct.id will always return id: 1 and cat_name: 'Mens'.
Shouldn't the category_tree CTE stop at "Mens > Tops"?

I would be grateful for any detailed explanations. Thank you very much.

See example. I added some additional data to your example to make the answer clearer.
Your data (source)



id
cat_name
parent_category_id




1
Mens
null


2
Tops
1


3
Jerseys
2


4
England-1
3


5
England-2
3



And recursive query
WITH RECURSIVE category_tree AS (
   SELECT 0 as lvl, id, cat_name, parent_category_id,
      cat_name AS full_name
   FROM categories
   WHERE parent_category_id IS NULL                
   UNION ALL                                       
   SELECT lvl+1 as lvl,c.id, c.cat_name,c.parent_category_id,
      CONCAT (ct.full_name, ' > ', c.cat_name)
   FROM category_tree ct 
   INNER JOIN categories c
            ON c.parent_category_id = ct.id             
    )
SELECT * 
FROM category_tree;




lvl
id
cat_name
parent_category_id
full_name




0
1
Mens
null
Mens


1
2
Tops
1
Mens > Tops


2
3
Jerseys
2
Mens > Tops > Jerseys


3
4
England-1
3
Mens > Tops > Jerseys > England-1


3
5
England-2
3
Mens > Tops > Jerseys > England-2



Let's look at the request step by step.  I'll add column lvl for step numbering.

The first step is to execute anchor part of query

   SELECT 0 as lvl, id, cat_name, parent_category_id,
      cat_name AS full_name
   FROM categories
   WHERE parent_category_id IS NULL                

Output is



lvl
id
cat_name
parent_category_id
full_name




0
1
Mens
null
Mens




Second step - JOIN (INNER) above result with source

   SELECT lvl+1 as lvl,c.id, c.cat_name,c.parent_category_id,
      CONCAT (ct.full_name, ' > ', c.cat_name)
   FROM category_tree ct 
   INNER JOIN categories c
            ON c.parent_category_id = ct.id             

This part output is



lvl
id
cat_name
parent_category_id
full_name




1
2
Tops
1
Mens > Tops



3.Union with anchor result is



lvl
id
cat_name
parent_category_id
full_name




0
1
Mens
null
Mens


1
2
Tops
1
Mens > Tops



4.Next step - recursive part of query - JOIN step 3 result with source.
We JOIN (INNER)



lvl
id
cat_name
parent_category_id
full_name




0
1
Mens
null
Mens


1
2
Tops
1
Mens > Tops



with source table.
JOIN result is



lvl
id
cat_name
parent_category_id
full_name




2
3
Jerseys
2
Mens > Tops > Jerseys



And after UNION ALL



lvl
id
cat_name
parent_category_id
full_name




0
1
Mens
null
Mens


1
2
Tops
1
Mens > Tops


2
3
Jerseys
2
Mens > Tops > Jerseys




Next step - JOIN (INNER) above output with source. This step is interesting because JOIN will output the result in 2 rows.
JOIN output is




lvl
id
cat_name
parent_category_id
full_name




3
4
England-1
3
Mens > Tops > Jerseys > England-1


3
5
England-2
3
Mens > Tops > Jerseys > England-2



After UNION ALL



lvl
id
cat_name
parent_category_id
full_name




0
1
Mens
null
Mens


1
2
Tops
1
Mens > Tops


2
3
Jerseys
2
Mens > Tops > Jerseys


3
4
England-1
3
Mens > Tops > Jerseys > England-1


3
5
England-2
3
Mens > Tops > Jerseys > England-2



fiddle

I cannot express how grateful I am for the detailed explanation of each line. Thank you very much!
